# Add box-shadow to a Boostrap Column

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I want to add a shadow to a Bootstrap column, in order to create a thing similar to the image attached.

I need this shadow to overlap images, other divs backgrounds, and everything in general.

What I want :

[image]

And here is my code: https://codepen.io/alejandring/pen/oLKArO`

```
        <div class="sidebar-logo">
            <img src="https://peg-n-rope-alejandroarias.c9users.io/v1/images/sidebar-logo.png"></img>
        </div>
        <h1 id="titleh1">explore barcelona</h1>
        <hr>
        <div id="menu-wrapper">
            <ul id="double">
              <li>top ten</li>
              <li>hotels</li>
              <li>features</li>
              <li>eat & drink</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="spotlight">
            <div style="text-align:center;">
               <p>Explore Spain</p>
               <hr>
               <p>Explore Europe</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End Of Sidebar-->
    <div id="main" class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                <div id="header">
                    <h1>La Sagrada Familia</h1>
                    <div class="menu">
                    <span id="map">FACTS</span>
                    <span id="facts">MAP</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="shadow"></div>-->
        <!--Enf of Header-->

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="weblist">
                <div><span class="numbered">1</span></div>
                <div><h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametumque quos est harum architecto?</h2></div>
            </div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, quia quam ullam dolore ut optio error voluptas aliquam dolorum vitae eos sint ea vel veritatis possimus iure perferendis molestiae est.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, ea, id officia atque placeat aut laudantium eveniet eius ex sequi impedit iste inventore sapiente veritatis rerum iure nesciunt facere autem!</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="weblist">
                <div><span class="numbered">1</span></div>
                <div><h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametumque quos est harum architecto?</h2></div>
            </div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, quia quam ullam dolore ut optio error voluptas aliquam dolorum vitae eos sint ea vel veritatis possimus iure perferendis molestiae est.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, ea, id officia atque placeat aut laudantium eveniet eius ex sequi impedit iste inventore sapiente veritatis rerum iure nesciunt facere autem!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="weblist">
                <div><span class="numbered">1</span></div>
                <div><h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametumque quos est harum architecto?</h2></div>
            </div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, quia quam ullam dolore ut optio error voluptas aliquam dolorum vitae eos sint ea vel veritatis possimus iure perferendis molestiae est.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa, ea, id officia atque placeat aut laudantium eveniet eius ex sequi impedit iste inventore sapiente veritatis rerum iure nesciunt facere autem!</p>
        </div>
        <!--End Of WebList-->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="facts">
                <h2>Facts</h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6"><img src="https://peg-n-rope-alejandroarias.c9users.io/v1/images/imageholder.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametumque quos est harum architecto?</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, tempora vel aliquid. Veritatis, perferendis, sapiente, in ratione nemo soluta suscipit dolor doloribus veniam ipsam molestias molestiae a quisquam amet temporibus.</p>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametumque quos est harum architecto?</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, tempora vel aliquid. Veritatis, perferendis, sapiente, in ratione nemo soluta suscipit dolor doloribus veniam ipsam molestias molestiae a quisquam amet temporibus.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"><img src="https://peg-n-rope-alejandroarias.c9users.io/v1/images/imageholder.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6"><img src="https://peg-n-rope-alejandroarias.c9users.io/v1/images/imageholder.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametumque quos est harum architecto?</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, tempora vel aliquid. Veritatis, perferendis, sapiente, in ratione nemo soluta suscipit dolor doloribus veniam ipsam molestias molestiae a quisquam amet temporibus.</p>
                        </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametumque quos est harum architecto?</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, tempora vel aliquid. Veritatis, perferendis, sapiente, in ratione nemo soluta suscipit dolor doloribus veniam ipsam molestias molestiae a quisquam amet temporibus.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"><img src="https://peg-n-rope-alejandroarias.c9users.io/v1/images/imageholder.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Enf Of Fats-->
        <div class="row" id="fast-facts">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="google-maps">
                    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyBlsDqeDCPYRgIj1Dpbv_VbLf14wUw4E10
&q=La+Barceloneta,Barcelona+ES" width="551" height="376" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
                </div>
                <!--End Of G-MAPS-->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h2>Fast Facts</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Map and Address</span></li>
                    <li><span>Website</span></li>
                    <li><span>Online Tickets</span></li>
                    <li><span>Time Needed: 1 - 2 hours</span></li>
                </ul>
                <img src="https://peg-n-rope-alejandroarias.c9users.io/v1/images/sficon.jpg" class="img-responsive"></img>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12"><h3><span>&#9658;</span> Other Barcelona Top 10 Attractions Near La Sagrada Familia Are Marked In Yellow</h3></div>
        </div>
        <!--Enf Of Fast-Facts-->

        <div class="row" id="visiting-tips">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>More Visiting Tips</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>Ensure you buy the entrance ticket and tower access online, the lines can get very long!</li>
                    <li>Don't reach before the time on your ticket, they won't let you earlier.</li>
                    <li>A small museum underneath tells the long history of building a basilica. Go if you have the time.</li>
                    <li>The towers have a great view across Barcelona.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End Of Visiting Tips-->

        <div class="row" id="related-links">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2>Related Links</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="padding-left:45px; padding-right:45px;">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img src="https://peg-n-rope-alejandroarias.c9users.io/v1/images/city.jpg" class="img-responsive"></img>
                    <h3>City</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img src="https://peg-n-rope-alejandroarias.c9users.io/v1/images/fivestarshotel.jpg" class="img-responsive"></img>
                    <h3>Five Stars Hotels</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img src="https://peg-n-rope-alejandroarias.c9users.io/v1/images/attractions.jpg" class="img-responsive"></img>
                    <h3>Attractions</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img src="https://peg-n-rope-alejandroarias.c9users.io/v1/images/zoos.jpg" class="img-responsive"></img>
                    <h3>Zoos</h3>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--End Of Related Links-->

        <div class="row" id="reviews">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2>Review And Feedback Of La Sagrada Familia</h2>
                <section>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus, neque, eligendi, suscipit, aut nisi laborum nostrum ad autem deserunt modi commodi ducimus libero fuga voluptate itaque accusamus officia voluptatem quas.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, vel, dicta saepe iusto aut suscipit voluptatum magnam maiores nulla molestiae odio rerum sapiente dolorum! In distinctio quae adipisci libero nobis.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem, officiis ipsum adipisci numquam temporibus quibusdam expedita esse animi? Cum, pariatur temporibus magnam sunt voluptates nihil facilis quas saepe? Quaerat, eum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita, architecto beatae et asperiores eos sit quos perspiciatis numquam quod saepe natus labore quisquam vitae omnis laborum aut facere dolor at.</p>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End Of Review-->

        <div class="row" id="quick-links">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h2>Destinations</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>Barcelona</li>
                    <li>Madrid</li>
                    <li>Seville</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h2>Top 10</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>Top 10 Things To Do in Barcelona</li>
                    <li>Top 10 Things To Do in Madrid</li>
                    <li>Top 10 Things To Do in Seville</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h2>Eat & Drink</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>Barcelona Eat & Drinks</li>
                    <li>Madrid Eat & Drinks</li>
                    <li>Seville Eat & Drinks</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h2>Hotels</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>Barcelona Hotels</li>
                    <li>Madrid Hotels</li>
                    <li>Seville Hotels</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End Of Quick-Links -->

        <div class="row" id="footer">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img alt="PegNRope" src="https://peg-n-rope-alejandroarias.c9users.io/v1/images/logo.png" width="123px" height="33px">
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">PEGNROPE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PRIVACY</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><p>PegNRope - Hotels, Experiences and Activities</p></div>
        </div>


    </div>
    <!--End of Main Page-->
    </div>
```

```
  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to your CSS file, and edit it as your need:

```
div#sidebar {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 25px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 25px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 25px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: That is a nice one. But I can't make it work as:

1) The Sidebar doesn't go all the page's height.

2) The shadow doesn't overlap other divs background, for instance.

You can check in here https://codepen.io/alejandring/pen/oLKArO (I've tricked the sidebar with some <p> tags).